# AES 128 Encryption on android

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android encryption/decryption with AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes)

For the last 7 days i was looking for one,just one android example working correctly regarding AES 128 encryption but i can't,can anybody help ?

Comment: Then I bet you didn't do any search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes

Comment: You do not say what you are encrypting. If you wish to encrypt a database, and you will "settle" for AES-256, use SQLCipher for Android: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: 7 days, srlsy ? http://whathaveyoutried.com ? (also, total duplicate => no search done.)

Comment: I'm confused why this was marked as a duplicate, since the referenced SO answer has numerous indications that it is actually wrong and creates a insecure solution on every one of the answers according to @maarten-bodewes Very confusing.

Answer (score -1):

how about http://code.google.com/p/aes-encryption-samples/wiki/HowToEncryptWithJava. i used it and it worked (i'm no expert!)

Comment: First of all let me thank you for your feedback,Can i ask you how i can call these classes from activity ?

Comment: well, i created a "sample" app w/ an EditText (for user input of a "clean" string), a button that gets that "clean" string and encrypts it, and a TextView to display the encrypted string. basic android dev stuff. The functions in the encrypt/decrypt classes are static, so you can call them by: `encryptedString = YourClassName.encrypt(seed, cleanString);`  etc.

Comment: but " encrypt " function recive :
- cipher
- dataBytes
did you mean cipher = seed 
and 
cleanString = dataBytes
?

Comment: there should only be two (2) PUBLIC functions: `encrypt(seed, cleanStr)` and 'decrypt(seed, encryptedStr)`

Comment: i swear that AES4all class has just two public functions and encrypt function takes parameter as is explain before .public static byte[] encrypt(Cipher cipher, byte[] dataBytes)

Comment: all i can say is take a peek at the code (link above)...follow it until you understand what it's doing. good luck!