# Decrypt the message in Android

Tags: android, message, encryption

I am working in one app where i need to implement the decryption of conversation.The conversations are encrypted using MD5 algorithm. I don't have any idea regarding this.

Could anybody help me out.thanks in advance!!!

Comment: please give some more details. which encrytption algorithm does your system use? or do you have to implement encryption part too?

Comment: @StinePike suppose i got message in encryption mode from some user i need to decrypt that ,how could i implement that.

Comment: If you don't have the decryption keys and don't know what type of encryption it is you are screwed...

Comment: @Neil yes ,suppose  i will create own encryption or MD5 encrption, then it will be fine right!!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you'll have to know *what* encryption is used exactly.

A range of cryptographic algorithms is implemented in Android's [Cipher class](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). If it's not in there, you'll have to find a third party implementation or roll your own.

Comment: @thanks Paul-Jan for you quick response suppose if will create own encryption process then it will be fine or not to decrypt!!

Comment: suppose MD5 encryption process is implemented then how to decrypt?

Comment: MD5 is a hash, not an encryption. **It cannot be decrypted**, you can only hash a different input set and test if it leads to the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings) you can see a simle encrypt/decrypt program using AES128 algorithm. If you search you can find plenty of so answers too lik [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788456/931982).

For md5 you can use [java.security.MessageDigestSpi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class. you can check any of these examples. I didn't try these examples so you need to verify :)

[link1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/), [link2](http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1199/Java-md5-example-with-MessageDigest), [link3](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-md5-hashing-salting-password/)

But first of all study over encrytpion algorithms, hashing to learn the basics

Comment: @thanks for your answer but the examples are using encrypt and decrypt of AES128 alg i need using MD5 hash key  !!