# Android - How to set password for sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

As the title of issue, how can I set password for sqlite database ?
Please tell me!
Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118793/android-sqlite-password-encryption
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680173/setting-password-for-android-sqlite-database

Comment: Not supported in android, I suggest encrypting data.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has hooks built-in for encryption which are not used in the normal distribution, but here are a few implementations I know of:

- -[SEE](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) The official implementation.
- -[wxSQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsqlite/) - A wxWidgets style c++ wrapper that also implements SQLite's encryption.
- -[SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) - Uses openSSL's libcrypto to implement.
- -[SQLiteCrypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm) - Custom implementation, modified API.
- -[botansqlite3](https://github.com/OlivierJG/botansqlite3) - botansqlite3 is an encryption codec for SQLite3 that can use any algorithms in Botan    for encryption.

The SEE and SQLiteCrypt require the purchase of a license.