# Looking for an encrypt/decrypt AES example for Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

As I am new to encryption and particularly in **Java/Android**, I am struggling to find tutorials and code that work fine so that I can learn from them but the results.

As in this site: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Cryptographic_Extensions

I couldn't find the problem that hit me with `BASE64Encoder` class, which seems to be inside package  a sun.utils but I can find `Base64` class but I could not tweak code so that it could work for me.

Similarly in this

[android encryption/decryption with AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes)

The encryption is done in `Bitmap Image` I could not realize the same technique in normal text string.

Would someone supply a simple AES encryption/decryption example in Android just showing how to use key,message, encryption and decryption?

Comment: is this for login or any other ?

Comment: this is for  hiding some data offline in resource which are strictly copyrighted and high in demand

Comment: This question was/is off-topic, since it is asking for an example. However it also seems to be a duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The encryption and decryption process worked fine after:
  **I replaced the byte array obtained from  :**

`Bitmap` 
by `byte array of message string` as instructed in

[android encryption/decryption with AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes)

So  even though my problem is not fully solved, this question should be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for my project.

```
'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'(ref: [enter link description here][1]
```

encryption:

```
String encryptedMsg = AESCrypt.encrypt(password, message);
```

decryption:

```
String messageAfterDecrypt = AESCrypt.decrypt(password, encryptedMsg);
```

if you are more concerned about security go with SHA1 or SHA256.
Hope this helps.

Edit:
In my case, i have to encrypt login password and send it to server over the network.

```
String userPassword = password.getText().toString();
try {
        encryptedMsg = AESCrypt.encrypt(userPassword, Config.secretlogin);
   } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

So in backend, i have decrypted the secure password with the key and in both sides i am using the same AES(Android and backend).

Comment: i tried it but it says bad padding exception  when i try to decrypt the data that i encrypted using AES encryption online
1.I encrypted the string using  http://aesencryption.net/  
2.I encryted the same string using the library your mentioned.
3. the encrypted data are different 
4.and android studio shows javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e06b065:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:BAD_DECRYPT  exception while decrypting

Comment: let me edit my answer with what i have tried in my case.

Comment: It is a deprecated repository

Comment: glad you mentioned it, can you update here whats the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

The second example should work for text strings. Replace

```
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

with

```
byte[] b = yourString.getBytes();
```

Note that you have to store the key in some way because at some point have to be deciphered

Stored on the device is not a good idea because you're leaving the key to the door. You can store on your server or use a passphrase (fixed or asked the user). I give you a real sample of the last option

```
private static String getPassphraseSize16(String key) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
        return null;
    }
    char controlChar = '\u0014';
    String key16 = key + controlChar;
    if (key16.length() < 16) {
        while (key16.length() < 16) {
            key16 += key + controlChar;
        }
    }
    if (key16.length() > 16) {
        key16 = key16.substring(key16.length() - 16, key16.length());
    }
    return key16;
}


public static byte[] encodeAES(byte[] message, String passphrase) {
    String passphrase16 = getPassphraseSize16(passphrase);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passphrase16.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encodedText = cipher.doFinal(message);

    return encodedText;
}


public static byte[] decodeAES(byte[] encodedMessage, String key) {
    String passphrase16 = getPassphraseSize16(key);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passphrase16.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decodedText = cipher.doFinal(encodedMessage);

    return decodedText;
}
```

This example is similar to provided in https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find the problem that hit me with BASE64Encoder class,
>   which seems to be inside package a sun.utils but i can find Base64
>   class but i could not tweak code so that it could work for me.

You might not be using the right library for Base64. You mention `sun.utils`, where the link you sent is using:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Since **Java 8**, you can use `java.util.Base64`, as detailed on Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). It supports Basic encoding, URL encoding and MIME encoding. You can find some examples in [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/base64-encoding-java-8).