# Md5 to String in android studio

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, md5

I am using Md5 for sharedpref 
now when I get the data shared but see encrypted it

```
 public static String md5(final String s) {
    final String MD5 = "MD5";
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance(MD5);
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

this codes for get the data from shared, I can not see data, i only see the encripted md5

```
 sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(nameshe,MODE_PRIVATE);
        String  nam=sharedPreferences.getString(sa,"jan");
        String names =md5(nam);
        textView.setText(names);
```

Comment: To understand your question, you want to decrypt your code when you pull it out of SharedPreferences?  Because if you encrypted it when you put it inside SharedPreferences, it will be encrypted when you pull it out.

Comment: Yes I want decrypt your code when you pull it out of SharedPreferences

Comment: MD5 is a hashing algorithm and and not an encryption algorithm. Therefore, you cannot convert it back to the original value. You might want to consider a different method for your needs.

Comment: You can tell me different method for encryption  ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-using-aes) is an example